# What would be a good build pattern for this situation? (partition tool)

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am developing a partition tool, and I am facing a problem in the design. I have a class (called CtrlFactories) that will read the MBR and build an object for each partition that is found in the MBR. I have a class for each type of partition and a Factory for each of them.

Here is how it looks like:

[image: UML]

(I've put only NTFS and FAT32 in the example, but I have one for each type of partition).

My idea was to put in the IFactory something like:

```
std::map< EPartType, IFactory* > mpFactories;
```

And build it in the constructor, or in some init function:

```
IFactory::IFactory()
{
    mpFactories[PART_NTFS] = new FactoryNTFS();
    mpFactories[PART_FAT32] = new FactoryFAT32();
    mpFactories[PART_EXT2] = new FactoryEXT2();
    ...
}
```

And in the "Build" function, do:

```
int CtrlFactories::Build()
{
    ...
    MBR mbr;
    BuildMBR( mbr );

    //... here I loop all the partitions found...
    for( /*each partition*/ )
    {
        IPartition* part = mpFactories[ mbr.GetPartType() ]->Build( mbr.PartPosition() );
        //..and store each partition somewhere
    }
}
```

The point is: I have lots of partition types (> 100), and in most of cases, the user will only have two or three different types of partitions in the HD. So it seems like a waste of time and memory to allocate all the factories and not using most of them. I think that a lazy initialization would be much better here, but then I would need somewhere a code like:

```
    switch( mbr.GetPartType() )
    {
    case PART_NTFS:
        if ( mpFactories[ PART_NTFS ] == NULL )
            mpFactories[PART_NTFS] = new FactoryNTFS();
        break;       

    case PART_FAT32:
        if ( mpFactories[ PART_32 ] == NULL )
            mpFactories[PART_32] = new Factory32();
        break;       

    ...
    }
```

}

And that very long switch/case would add too much ciclomatic complexity to the code (even the code being easy to understand).

So, is there a better solution for the problem, that can avoid the very long "switch/case" and that does not waste resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to implement the factories with the Singleton pattern.  Have a static `Instance()` method on each factory class that manages it's instantiation.  Then in your map you could store a function pointer to that method.

In your `Build()` code you're then looking up a pointer to the `Instance()` method for the factory for each partition you come across.  Use that pointer to get the actual factory you need, and then proceed from there.

Comment: Thank you! That's an interesting approach for the problem.